# Bot Persist state of user during conversation

Tags: python-telegram-bot

Every time that I restart my app (bot), conversation states are lost.
Is it possible to persist user state in a storage (like redis or a database) during conversations? How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

This feature is currently in `master` branch now. There are 2 main classes: `DictPersistance` and `PicklePersistance`.

Of course, you can write your own implementation with Redis or Database using `BasePersistance` class.

See [Gihub PR](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/pull/1017).